# Input array in Keras CNN

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

What does the '?' in the input and output arrays mean?
What all I do to make it 'None' ?  (Please refer the image attached)

This is my code for getting the input data.

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip = True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_path,
                                                 target_size = (128, 128),
                                                 batch_size = 64,
                                                 class_mode = 'categorical')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(valid_path,
                                            target_size = (128, 128),
                                            batch_size = 64,
                                            class_mode = 'categorical')
```

[image]

Comment: ? is supposed to be the number of samples

Comment: ? is unknown(or set to None). When you do not specify number of data points(like number of images, etc). when you put data at the end, it will contain the number of samples.

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow uses four channels, where the first one(represented by ? or None) represents a batch_size that you will be passing, at training. You might wonder why None? Well because that batch_size is flexible, always defined by the user, so Tensorflow uses ? or None as a placeholder, until the batch size is passed. The other three channels are obviously the dimensions

Comment: So, ? and None mean the same?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, it's just a placeholder for your batch_size